# Email Client that Automatically Sends

Tags: email

I am wondering if there is a free email client that automatically sends the email without needing to be open? I'm assuming this email client would have to install a service to do this.

I think the newer versions of outlook can do this, but the version I have, does not do this.

Comment: You really need to rephrase your question.  An email client which sends "the email" without needing to be open?  I have no idea what that means.

Comment: You aren't looking for an email client, you are looking for a mailer daemon or something. No client would automatically start sending emails... it doesn't make sense for a "client" to do that..

Comment: Perhaps he wants to send emails from the command line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I'm aware there is no way for a closed application to do anything unless it's on some sort of timer or cron job to open every 5 minutes then close. Also as far as I know, no version of Outlook is capable of this, in fact they will prompt you to attempt to send anything in your outbox prior to closing because of this exact reason.

I know I have written programs to send emails, but these were all web apps and did it directly using the System.Net.Mail class. But then again it was all processed on a server, not on the client side.

Comment: Yea, I don't understand why this application just doesn't do it on the server side. I may have to download a printer driver that will email the file.

Answer (score 0):

You can [telnet to port 25 of a remote mail server](http://www.garnetchaney.com/how_to_telnet_to_a_mail_server.shtml).  You don't need much of anything to be running on your local machine to do that.  Of course, the remote mail server needs to be happy about you telnetting to its port 25.

The mail sending facilities of early UNIX mail clients were just simple wrappers for doing this.